# Empty ObjectSets in TryGetObjectByKey

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

When I use `TryGetObjectByKey` on my `ObjectContext`, it returns an error. An item with a duplicate value already exists.

When I look at my `objectContext`, I see that the `ObjectSet`s are empty. What am I doing wrong? When I enumerate the `ObjectSet` by hand, by using `ToArray` on it, or by using the debugger, it does work.

`LazyLoadingEnabled` is set to `true`.

I reuse 2 tables from another EDMX, but they are in different namespaces and they are not the `objectSet`s I try to approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699802/argument-exception-after-trying-to-use-trygetobjectbykey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not a duplicate. Its different.Sort of...

I finally found the solution. The Entity framework doesnt load the metadata correctly for POCO.

what you have to do on your OnContextCreated is this:

databaseContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(typeof(Entity).Assembly);

This will correctly load the metadata and it works.... I need to read into it... but this seems to do the trick.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataservices/thread/601491ab-9c46-4fdf-88a7-c7392e5dbcdf

Comment: You could post this answer under the original question.